# Salutation rule is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am currently working on Salutation rule. I made for English and German. However, Salutation for German is not working while English Salutation works fine.
Can you guys help me to find where is the error within the German Salutation? Thanks.

This is for English Salutation.

```ampscript
%%[ 

SET @FirstName = propercase(@FirstName) 
SET @LastName = propercase(@LastName) 

If empty(@salutation) 
   or @FirstName == 'Max' 
   or @LastName == 'Mustermann' 
   or empty(@FirstName) 
   or empty(@LastName) then 

   SET @WelcomeText = "Greetings," 
   SET @SubjectLineTitle = "" 

elseif @Salutation == 'Mx' 
       and @FirstName != 'Max' 
       and @LastName != 'Mustermann' then 

    SET @WelcomeText = Concat("Greetings ",@FirstName," ", @LastName,",") 
    SET @SubjectLineTitle = Concat(", ",@FirstName," ",@LastName) 

elseif (
         (
          @Salutation == 'Mr' 
          or @Salutation == 'Mrs' 
          or @Salutation == 'Ms' 
          or @Salutation == 'Miss' 
          or @Salutation == 'Dr' 
          or @Salutation == 'Prof.'
         ) and (
          @FirstName != 'Max' 
          and @LastName != 'Mustermann'
         )
       ) then 

    SET @WelcomeText = Concat("Dear ",@Salutation," ", @LastName,",") 
    SET @SubjectLineTitle = Concat(", ",@salutation," ",@LastName) 

else 

    SET @WelcomeText = "Greetings," 
    SET @SubjectLineTitle = "" 
    
endif 
]%%
%%=v(@WelcomeText)=%%
```

This is German Salutation.

```ampscript
%%[ 

SET @FirstName = propercase(@FirstName) 
SET @LastName = propercase(@LastName) 

If empty(@salutation) 
   or @FirstName == 'Max' 
   or @LastName == 'Mustermann' 
   or empty(@FirstName) 
   or empty(@LastName)  then 

  SET @WelcomeText = "Guten Tag," 
  SET @SubjectLineTitle = "" 

elseif (
        (
          @Salutation == 'Herr' 
          or @Salutation == 'Herr Dr.' 
          or @Salutation == 'Herr Prof.'
        ) and (
            @FirstName != 'Max' 
            and @LastName != 'Mustermann'
        )
       ) then 

    SET @WelcomeText = Concat("Lieber ",@Salutation," ", @LastName,",") 
    SET @SubjectLineTitle = Concat(", ",@salutation," ",@LastName) 

elseif (
        (
          @Salutation == 'Frau' 
          or @Salutation == 'Frau Dr.' 
          or @Salutation == 'Frau Prof.'
        ) and (
          @FirstName != 'Max' 
          and @LastName != 'Mustermann'
        )
       ) then 

    SET @WelcomeText = Concat("Liebe ",@Salutation," ", @LastName,",") 
    SET @SubjectLineTitle = Concat(", ",@salutation," ",@LastName) 

elseif (
        (
         @Salutation == 'Dr.' 
         or @Salutation == 'Prof.'
        ) and (
         @FirstName != 'Max' 
         and @LastName != 'Mustermann'
        )
       ) then 

    SET @WelcomeText = Concat("Guten Tag ",@Salutation," ",@FirstName," ", @LastName,",") 
    SET @SubjectLineTitle = Concat(", ",@FirstName," ",@LastName) 

elseif (
        (
          @Salutation == 'Divers'
        ) and (
          @FirstName != 'Max' 
          and @LastName != 'Mustermann'
        )
       ) then 

    SET @WelcomeText = Concat("Guten Tag ",@FirstName," ", @LastName,",") 
    SET @SubjectLineTitle = Concat(", ",@FirstName," ",@LastName) 

else 

    SET @WelcomeText = "Guten Tag," 
    SET @SubjectLineTitle = "" 

endif
]%%
%%=v(@WelcomeText)=%%
```

Thank you all

Comment: a `set @salutation` statement is missing form your script, where do you set it?

Comment: What's not working, exactly?  Can you please update your question to include the inputs from your send context and the actual and desired output?

Comment: Also the `@Salutation` values in the conditionals are inconsistent regarding the punctuation, e.g. `@Salutation == 'Dr' ` vs `@Salutation == 'Dr.'`.  As [@zuzannamj](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50456/zuzannamj) pointed out, the values you're expecting for `@Salutation` are important.